# Given two rvs $X$ and $Y$, if $X Y = Z$, is it possible to change the mean and sd of $X$ without changing the mean and sd of $Y$ and $Z$

Tags: distributions, variance, mean, expected-value, moments

I have two lognormal rvs $X$ and $Y$, and a third rv $Z$ which is the product of the former two. I know the mean and standard deviation of the three.

Is it possible to calculate an alternative pair of $\mu$ and $\sigma$ the mean and standard deviation of $X$ that follows a specific coefficient of variation ($\sigma/\mu$), but without changing the mean and standard deviation of $Z$?

Let's consider $X$ and $Y$ are independent variables, although I would like to understand how the solution changes if they are correlated.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "re-calculate the values"?  Note, too, that for a Lognormal distribution, $\mu$ and $\sigma$ determine the CV.  And do you assume $X$ and $Y$ are independent or not?

Comment: Thanks @whuber, just made some changes

Comment: It might be helpful to think about reframing the question on the log scale. $X_1=\log(X)$ etc. Then $Z_1 = X_1 + Y_1$, and $X_1$ and $Y_1$ are marginally normal.

Comment: I think this is just asking: Are there lognormal distributions $U,V,X,Y$ where $U\neq X$, $V\neq Y$ but $U\perp V$, $X\perp Y$, $UV=XY$, and $\mu_U/\sigma_U=\mu_X/\sigma_X$? If so, I recommend using that phrasing, and clarifying whether $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are the mean and standard derivation of the lognormal, or the parameters of the lognormal which are the mean and standard derivation of the corresponding normal.